# XCode trying to locate service account file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I try to build my Project in XCode, I get the following dialog box:

[image: dialog]
It asks for a `service account file` which I am not sure of.
If I cancel it, I get the following error in `upload-symbol-util.bash` file:

```
# If the token will expire in the next sixty seconds (or already
# has), reload it.
if ! fcr_verify_tok_plist; then
    xcdebug "Token is invalid. Refreshing..."
    if ! fcr_verify_svc_plist; then
        xcdebug "Service account information is invalid. Requesting reload..."
        if [[ "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE" && -f "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE" ]]; then
            xcdebug "Using $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE for credentials."
        else
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE="$(/usr/bin/osascript -e 'the POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Where is the service account file?" of type "public.json")' 2>/dev/null)"
        fi

        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$SVC_PLIST" \
            -c "Add :version integer 1"

        if [[ "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE" && -f "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE" ]]; then
            /usr/bin/plutil -replace "$APP_KEY" -json "$(/bin/cat "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE")" "$SVC_PLIST" || return 2

            if fcr_verify_svc_plist; then
                xcdebug "Installed service account file into $SVC_PLIST."
            else
                /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$SVC_PLIST" -c "Delete $APP_KEY" >/dev/null 2>&1
                xcerror "Unable to parse service account file."
                return 2
            fi
        else
            xcerror "User cancelled symbol uploading." // Getting Error here
            return 1
        fi
    fi
```

Please tell what is a `Service Account file` and where do I find it?

Comment: i ran into this once, which was really annoying. I couldn't find a fix so i ended up deleting and reinstalling Xcode along with all the simulators and it seemed to work fine :/

Comment: @Konsy but my other projects are working fine

Comment: that's really odd then, i had the issue with the majority of my projects which i checked... I haven't a clue, sorry!